# How do I return a callback from react hooks back the parent component? like returning the list of uploaded url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I return a callback from react hooks back the parent component? like returning the list of uploaded url.

child components/hook

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'

const ImageUploader = () => {
  const maxSize = 1048576;

  const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
    console.log(acceptedFiles);

  }, []);

  const { isDragActive, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragReject, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: ['image/png', 'image/jpg'],
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize: 5242880,
    multiple: true
  });

  const isFileTooLarge = rejectedFiles.length > 0 && rejectedFiles[0].size > maxSize;

  return (
    <div className="container text-center mt-5">
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        Click here or drop a file to upload!
      </div>
      <ul className="list-group mt-2">
        {acceptedFiles.length > 0 && acceptedFiles.map(acceptedFile => (
          <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
            {acceptedFile.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageUploader;
```

Comment: I think maybe there is confusion. `useCallback` hook memoizes a callback a component passes to *its children*. If `ImageUploader` needs to pass data back up to *its parent* then that parent needs to pass a callback to `ImageUploader` for it to call with data. I don't see any props being passed to `ImageUploader` nor any indication of a redux useDispatch (or similar) for global state.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent should pass as prop the setter for the state that store the list of accepted file (I suppose is an Array)

```
const Parent = () =>{
const [fileUploaded, setFileUploaded] = useState([])

return <><ImageUploader setFileUploaded={setFileUploaded} /></>
}
```

Then inside ImageUploader

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'

const ImageUploader = ({setFileUploaded}) => {
  const maxSize = 1048576;

  const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
    setFileUploaded(acceptedFiles);
  }, []);

  const { isDragActive, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragReject, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: ['image/png', 'image/jpg'],
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize: 5242880,
    multiple: true
  });

  const isFileTooLarge = rejectedFiles.length > 0 && rejectedFiles[0].size > maxSize;

  return (
    <div className="container text-center mt-5">
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        Click here or drop a file to upload!
      </div>
      <ul className="list-group mt-2">
        {acceptedFiles.length > 0 && acceptedFiles.map(acceptedFile => (
          <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
            {acceptedFile.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ImageUploader;
```